# Why does the MINIX installation ask how big /home should be?

Tags: partition, minix

While installing MINIX is was asked how big do want `/home` to be.

> --- Step 5: Select the size of /home ---------------
>
> MINIX will take up 611 MB, without /home.
>
> How big do you want your /home to be in MB (0-1435) ? [287]

After pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>

> 287 MB Ok? [Y]

What's the reason of asking that? Is it possible to change it later on?

I was never asked such a question while install Ubuntu (Linux) and I'm free (guessing) to store as much data in it as I want, limited by the partition size.

Installing on 2 GB virtual drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal Minix file system partitions can be further divided into up to four subpartitions. According to the [install guide](http://www.minix3.org/doc/A-312.html), the installer will take the partition you specified earlier and subpartition it into `root`, `/usr`, and `/home`; it's asking you how large you want `/home` to be.

A comparable Ubuntu example would be if you selected "Specify partitions manually"  in the installer and told it to make a new partition mounted at `/home`. The installer would ask you how big you want that partition to be:

[image]